# How can I rollback PHP from 7.0.32 to 7.0.30?

Tags: php, rollback, php-7.0

Last week I did an "apt upgrade" as I always did, but this time I forgot to create a full system image for backup in case anything happened.

And what happened? My system was very unstable. Of course.

***So I would like to know if there is a way to rollback a specific version of PHP (7.0.32) to the previous version (7.0.30).***

I have not found anything on the web, just links here in StackOverflow and other sites that teach how to rollback entire versions, such as 7.1 to 7.0 or 7.2 to 5.6 and so on.

I have root access and everything. Anyone have any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: If you upgraded all the packages, why do you think it's php that is to blame? What distro do you have? Where did you install php from? What's the exact package name? "how to rollback entire versions" --- there is no difference between downgrading a package from `x.a to x.b` and `x.y.a to x.y.b`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by zerkms, I was able to rollback using specific versions and the problem persisted. After a lot of research I discovered that it was a problem with IPV6 routes, it was not a problem with my system or the updates made on the server. Thank you for your help!